# Pumping speed between atmosphere and atmosphere

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, ideal-gas, bernoulli-equation, gas

How to determine flow rate at which air passes through system consisting of an air pump and pipe with a nozzle? In all publications I've found it is important to know the pressure drop, but there's no pressure drop in my system. Nozzle and pump's outlet are in the same room. I am inducing air flow, but not pressure differences.

So how to calculate the rate of that air flow? Am I right by saying, that it cannot surpass the conductance of nozzle?

Comment: It's not talking room pressure.  There should be a pressure difference at the nozzle if it is actually changing the velocity (or if anything is even flowing through it).

Comment: @Jmac But I don't know the pressure distance at the nozzle and I can't measure it by adding a gauge into the system.

Comment: If you have a pump there should be some pressure above atmospheric.  You could also just measure the exit velocity.

Comment: @Jmac I can't measure the exit velocity with the nozzle attached.  So now the most important question is that about "Am I right by saying, that flow rate cannot surpass the conductance of nozzle?"

Comment: I've never heard of the term "conductance" in a nozzle.  What do you mean by that?

Comment: @Jmac It is the amount of air that can pass through a component per unit time. Like here: https://www.pfeiffer-vacuum.com/filepool/File/Vacuum-Technology-Book/Vacuum-Technology-Book-II-Part-2.pdf?referer=2012&request_locale=en_US

Answer (score 1):

Conductance like the reciprocal of resistance in an analogous electrical circuit.

Just like resistance; it can be used to determine flow rate (or current in a circuit) when we know the potential difference.  In this case the potential difference is pressure.  You have to know the pressure along with the conductance to determine the air flow through the orifice.

The conductance itself is a measure of flow relative to a potential difference.  If you don't know that, we only know the ratio of flow to pressure difference.